# Bind Data in a asp:CheckBoxList using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp:checkbox list control

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkProperty" runat="server"> </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

also a button control

```
<asp:Button OnClick="FillCheckBox();"><asp:Button>
```

How can i bind some dummy data in the checkbox list control when button click event fires using jquery

what i tried is on botton click

```
   objXML_RegionData.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
    xpath = "//Name";
    result = objXML_RegionData.selectNodes(xpath);
    var row = $("[id*=chkProperty] tr:last-child").clone(true);
    $("[id*=chkProperty] tr").remove();
    $.each(result , function () {
        var customer = $(this);
        $("input", row).val($(this).attr("CustomerID"));
        $("label", row).html($(this).attr("ContactName"));
        $("[id*=chkProperty] tbody").append(row);
        row = $("[id*=chkProperty] tr:last-child").clone(true);
    });
```

i tried binding contact name as text and customer id  as value of the chekbox list.But nothing is displaying

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong, try like this,

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="FillCheckBox"></asp:Button>
```

In c#

```
 protected void FillCheckBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("Dummy data 1");
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("Dummy data 2");
}
```

Using this you can bind datas to checkboxlist. Let me know the result.